# hosting web-app on windows server (windows 11)

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, networking, hosting

I decided to create web-server on my home laptop, it uses windows server (windows 11), also I have static public IP address
web server is working in docker containers, it uses nginx container for requests, it works well on my vps server (ubunta OS), but when I decided to make my home server I came with troubles (it works in localhost)

- cannot get response through the internet to myapp (I have checked that traffic goes to my laptop through router, I started nginx server, and get responses through the Internet with public IP)

I have checked my firewall settings, I created rules to traffic in and out on ports 80/443
What are the possible reasons of thid problem (I suppose it is related to windows server features as my app works stable with the same configuration on nginx and docker-compose and I have checked that standalone nginx works on my home hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker running on win-server has a specific network configuration

as a solution to the problem, I suggest trying to run nginx for windows as a reverse proxy for your service running inside docker.